# Efficient gzip writing with gzprintf

Tags: c, zlib

### Context

I am currently writing a very large file of the following (uncompressed) format:

```
1
2
1
1
...
```

There is one integer in text form per line, with a significant amount of repetition.

I am writing the data out from an array with the C zlib stdio-style interface:

```
gzFile file = gzopen("myfile.gz", "w");

for (i=0; i<nlines; i++)
    gzprintf(file, "%d\n", array[i]);

gzclose(file);
```

Due to the high degree of repetition, the compressed file is extremely small compared to the source (3.7GB down to 5.3MB), however it takes a long time to write out.

### Question

I am not familiar with the compression algorithm or implementation, however  I am concerned that doing a very large number (~2 billion) calls to `gzprintf` with short character strings may cause some sort of bottleneck. I tried increasing the buffer size with `gzbuffer`, but this had little effect.

Is the way that I am using zlib appropriate, and are there any low hanging fruit for speeding up compression in this application?

Comment: If there is one *digit* per text line, you could encode each value in a nibble (2 per byte) before writing to a binary file, and reduce the output to a quarter (or a sixth if the text EOL marker is CR/LF pair), and you could go on from there by preparing an array of bytes to write, reducing the number of system calls. Or, you could buffer a lot of text lines internally to your program as one string, again to reduce the number of system calls.

Comment: To be clear, your first suggestion is to change the data format to a binary format? Unfortunately I am unable to change the format. I'm not quite sure what a nibble is though, so I'm not sure if that is what you're suggesting. I will try out your buffering solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the number of system calls by preparing an internal buffer of several lines. This will speed up your program significantly. As an example, but writing to `stdout` instead of using `gzprintf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ITEMS_PER_LINE  4
#define nlines          20

int main(){
    char buffer [ITEMS_PER_LINE*2 + 1];
    int array [nlines] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int i, j;
    char *cptr;

    for (i=0; i<nlines; i+=ITEMS_PER_LINE) {
        cptr = buffer;
        for (j=0; j<ITEMS_PER_LINE; j++) {
            if (i+j >= nlines) break;
            cptr += sprintf (cptr, "%d\n", array[i+j]);
        }
        printf("%s", buffer);
        //gzprintf(file, "%s", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously `buffer` will need to be larger if the numbers are >= 10.

Comment: Thanks, I used your solution, which results in speed improvements of around 27.5% for a large file, buffering 1000 lines. 100 lines gives a similar speedup of 27.0%. @psmears' solution below gave a slightly better speedup of 33.3%, however I stuck with yours as I preferred to stick with direct use of the `zlib` library.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the precise details of your application, it's worth considering using an external gzip process with a pipe:

```
FILE *pipe = popen("gzip - > myfile.gz", "w");

for (i=0; i<nlines; i++) {
    fprintf(pipe, "%d\n", array[i]);
}

pclose(pipe);
```

The advantage of this is that, on a multi-core machine (which is most computers these days), your program's processing and the compression can happen in parallel, on separate cores.

Whether this is a good idea will depend on a number of factors, including how much CPU your program uses: if it is genuinely just reading values out of an array, there may not be much gain (or indeed it may slow down due to the extra IPC involved). But if you're doing some nontrivial processing, you may see a speedup.

Given that it's relatively easy to modify your program to do this, it's definitely worth trying it (and measuring - with all performance "enhancements", always measure to be sure!).

Comment: Thanks, this solution had the best speed improvement relative to my initial implementation (33.3%), though since this represents only a modest improvement above @Weather's solution above, I decided to stick with his solution which does not rely on the existence of the `gzip` executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set compression level as well as compression method in the second parameter of gzopen. For example the following will use compression level 4 instead of the default 9.

```
gzopen("myfile.gz", "w4");
```